# Is there a kanji term for a leaf blower?

Tags: word-choice, words

What is the Japanese word for a leaf blower? I am searching for a kanji term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ブロワー,ブロアー and 送風機 are used though all of them are not common for people who doesn’t have it.

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/送風機%20 seems to mean ventilator.

Comment: 送風機 can mean both of them. I referred to this. https://s.kakaku.com/agriculture/ss_0029_0017/0036/%91%97%95%97%8B%40/search_itemlist.aspx?ssi_kw=%91%97%95%97%8B%40

Comment: it seems like the word blower and vacuum are used as well. The device can work 2 ways.

Comment: I think some blower have both functions.送風機 can mean both just blower and blower that can vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Amazon Japan](https://www.amazon.co.jp/s?k=%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%83%96%E3%83%AD%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC&__mk_ja_JP=%E3%82%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%82%AB%E3%83%8A&ref=nb_sb_noss_1) it is `ブロワ` or `ブロワー`。 Sometimes they say `リーフブロワー`.

There is no difference between `ブロワ` and `ブロワー`. Its just the matter of preference.